# How do I execute a python script from the command line using custom commands?

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I apologize in advance if my terminology is off, but what I want to do is execute a python script using a custom command. So for example, I want to write a python script that accepts some shell arguments and performs some arbitrary shell commands. We'll call this script random.py. Instead of typing:

```
> python random.py arguments go here
```

I would like to be able to type something like:

```
> random arguments go here
```

So in other words, I want to get rid of the python command and omit the .py. 
I realize that I could use an alias but I also want to make this script available for anyone else that wants to use it, and I don't want to ask them to make an alias.

Basically what I'm after is something like meteor js, zurb foundation, or grunt.
After I installed meteor I was able to create a new application by going to the shell and typing:

```
> meteor create --newapplicationname
```

Same concept with foundation and grunt. That's the type of functionality I'm after.
Any resources on how to do that sort of thing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the comment `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the beginning of your .py file and mark it as executable with `chmod a+x random.py`.

Comment: If you do what martineau suggests, you can also get rid of the `.py` extension if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for me (Ubuntu) is putting a symbolic link in /usr/local/bin like this,

```
$> sudo ln -s /path/to/your/python/script/random.py /usr/local/bin/random
$> sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/random
```

(If you want to automate this step just put these two commands in a bash script).
Normally the terminal should now find the script and execute it if you just type

```
$> random arg1 arg2
```

Just make sure your python script starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Setuptools for distributing you project, you can use [Automatic Script Creation](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html?highlight=console_scripts#automatic-script-creation) feature. Just put into setup.py script following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name = "Random",
    version = "0.1",
    packages = find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            'random = random:main_func',
        ],
    }
)
```

A shell script "random", which actually runs function "main_func" from module "random", will be available after project installation.