# How Can I Execute A Python Script By Just Typing The Script's Name?

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, osx-yosemite

I have a python script that I want to execute from the terminal, but I don't want to use the command `python`*`scriptName.py`*, instead, I'd like to just type `scriptName`. Is that possible? If it is, how?

I had a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497126/how-do-i-execute-a-python-script-from-the-command-line-using-custom-commands) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400381/calling-a-python-script-from-command-line-without-typing-python-first), but it doesn't work (probably because I'm on a different os).

I'm using python 2.7.9 on osx Yosemite (10.10.3).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a python script from command line without typing "python" first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400381/calling-a-python-script-from-command-line-without-typing-python-first)

Comment: That is run on linux

Comment: The mechanism is the same on any remotely U*x-flavored system. In fact, the environment (Bash) is exactly the same (albeit an older version on OSX).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this as the first line in your Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

(or wherever your Python interpreter lives).

Then give the script the executable bit:

```
chmod +x scriptName.py
```

Now you should be able to execute it like `./scriptName.py`. You can then put a symlink without the `.py` extension somewhere in your path.

Comment: What do you mean by "add a symlink"?

Comment: I tried your answer, but I'm not able, after adding the line `#!/usr/bin/python` and doing `chmod +x pythontool.py`(pythontool.py is my file), to type into the terminal `./pythontool.py` and run my file. Does this have something to do with bash?

Comment: @DCPY: Did you check that the path to the python interpreter is correct? You can type `which python` at the terminal to find out.

Comment: it displays `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`.

Comment: @DCPY: You have to put then into the header then instead. These are basic bash things, you can read up on it.